# open a new JDialog only once when JButton is clicked

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jbutton, jdialog

How can stop duplicate of `JDialog` opening up upon clicking `JButton` twice or more?

Comment: not wrong desing, not good idea, create only one `JDialog` and re_use for next event from `JButton`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can:

1. Make that dialog [*modal*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20boolean%29).
2. Use a `boolean` flag to indicate whether the dialog was already opened or not. Set when opening, clear when dialog is closed.